# Powershell Datetime::Parseexact with multiple formats

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to use parseexact , however the dates that I have are in multiple formats. I tried

```
$format =@('yyMMddHHmm') 
[System.DateTime]::ParseExact('1605221412',$format,$null)
```

and everything is fine
When I try to add another format I get an exception

```
$format =@('yyMMddHHmm', 'yyyyMMddHHmm') 
[System.DateTime]::ParseExact('1605221412',$format,$null,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
```

I tried double quotes, writing inline , various ways of trying to pass an array as the second argument.

```
[System.DateTime]::ParseExact('1605221412','yyMMddHHmm, yyyyMMddHHmm',$null,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
```

What am I missing ?
Is it possible to use ParseExact for multiple formats without doing a bunch of if, then , else statements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it just fine, the only problem is that `@(..)` is `object[]` not `string[]`:

```bash
$datesToTest = '1605221412', '09/02/2022', '02-09-2022'
[string[]] $formats = 'yyMMddHHmm', 'yyyyMMddHHmm', 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'dd-MM-yyyy'
$datesToTest | ForEach-Object {
    [datetime]::ParseExact(
        $_,
        $formats,
        [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
}
```

- **See [`ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles)).**

Comment: Thanks. Just learning Powershell now

Comment: @GoGoPuffs happy to help :)